# Wpf change the background colour of an expander's header only

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, expander

I have looked at many questions/answers but couldn't find what I was exactly looking for,

I am trying to change the background colour of the expander's header only and not have the same colour continue for the content within the expander. Preferably within xaml but a vb.net solution would suffice.

(Any comments or suggestions will be helpful)

If this is a duplicated question please direct me to the answer and leave the question open to help others avoid the same issue in the future!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you are exactly looking for, but you could change the header background by simply doing that:

```
 <Expander VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Expander.Header>
            <Grid Background="LightBlue">
                <TextBlock Text="Expander Header"/>
            </Grid>
        </Expander.Header>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Cotent"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
```

[image]

Or you could override the default `Expander`'s `Header` `DataTemplate` by using `HeaderTemplate`

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="HeaderText">
        <Border Height="25" Background="LightBlue">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
                    Margin="4 0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Foreground="White"
                    FontSize="11" 
                    FontWeight="Normal"
                   />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate" Value="{StaticResource HeaderText}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>


<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Expander VerticalAlignment="Center" Header="Expander Header">        
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Cotent"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Great answer, the top solution worked fine and is exactly what I was looking for :) @SamTheDev

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with getting the header background set.
I found the easiets weay to do it was to simply make a coloured rectangle and put it behind the expander. (use Margin and Height to make it fit)

```
<Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Fill="LightBlue" Height="33" Margin="0,0,0,-35" />
```

or use a border if you want rounded corners:

```
<Border CornerRadius="15" Height="33" Margin="0,0,0,-35" Background="LightBlue" />
```